# Can we use vue splice inside foreach() to delete multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a image grid(in array form),
[image: Image Grid UI]

There I am trying to add multi-deletion functionality.

[image: ImageGrid array]

So When checkbox of each image from grid is checked, I am maintaining an array named selectedImages with selected image's Index from imagegrid array

[image: selectedImages Array]

and on click of delete button I have coded below remove method:

```
     removeSelectedImages() {
        console.log(this.additionalPhotos);  //ImageGrid array
        console.log(this.selectedImages);  //selectedImages array

        this.selectedImages.sort().reverse();
         this.selectedImages.forEach((selectedImageIndex, index) => {
        this.additionalPhotos.splice(selectedImageIndex, 1);
        this.selectedImages.splice(index, 1);
        });
      },
```

But issue I am facing is splice is just working once, initially I thought that is because suppose I reset value of index 2 and when it comes to index 3 then it becomes index 2 so issue is coming. so as solution I have reversed selected images array based in value (indexes of Grid image array) but still it is behaving same.

suppose I selected image 2 & 1 but splice only deleting value 2 second time it is not coming inside loop however if I remove splice then it runs 2 times.

Kindly suggest best method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to `filter` deleted images:

```js
let additionalPhotos = [{fileSrc: 'aa', fileName: '1.png'}, {fileSrc: 'bb', fileName: '2.png'}, {fileSrc: 'cc', fileName: '3.png'}, {fileSrc: 'dd', fileName: '4.png'}, {fileSrc: 'ee', fileName: '5.png'}, {fileSrc: 'ff', fileName: '6.png'},]
const selectedImages = [2,4]
function removeSelectedImages() {
  additionalPhotos = additionalPhotos.filter((_, idx) => {
    return !selectedImages.includes(idx)
  })
}
removeSelectedImages()
console.log(additionalPhotos)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Nikola. 

using above code is giving me below error

Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'additionalPhotos'
    at Proxy.removeSelectedImages

in my case I have multi-dimensional array so I am using index rathe than value like below:

 const additionalPhotos = this.additionalPhotos.filter((images, index) => {
          console.log(index + '---' + this.selectedImages.includes(index));
          return !this.selectedImages.includes(index);
        });

Comment: @Khushi hey mate take a look again at my answer, it is updated so now it use indexes for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
removeSelectedImages() {
   console.log(this.additionalPhotos);  //ImageGrid array
   console.log(this.selectedImages);  //selectedImages array

   this.selectedImages.sort()
   let c
   for (c=selectedImages.length-1; c>=0; c--) {
      this.additionalPhotos.splice(selectedImages[c],1)
   } 
   this.selectedImages=[]    
}
```